Is the unbounded derived $\infty$-category of a general abelian category stable?
Let $A$ be any abelian category. Consider the stable $\infty$-category $N_{dg}(Ch(A))$ defined as the differential graded nerve of the category of chain complexes $Ch(A)$ in $A$. We can define an $\infty$-category
$$D(A):= N_{dg}(Ch(A))[W^{-1}]$$
by inverting the quasi-isomorphisms.
I want to ask, for general $A$, is $D(A)$ a stable $\infty$-category?
I'm aware of the following facts:
(1) If $A$ is Grothendieck, then the answer is yes (say by the results in Lurie's HA.1.3.5)
(2) If $A$ is small, then the homotopy category $hD(A)$ has a natural triangulated structure (by the classical theory of localization of triangulated categories)

Perhaps the answer is YES, but it might happen that $D(A)$ lives in another Grothendieck's universe.

Well, Groth in one of his papers on derivators noted that a derivator/infinity-category is stable iff finite limits commute with finite colimits. I'm not well versed in those matters, but it seems like a property you can check directly.

The category of unbounded chain complexes on any additive category form a stable model category with chain homotopy equivalences as weak equivalences and degreewise split monomorphisms as cofibrations (exercise!). Thefore, the Dwyer-Kan localization of unbounded chain complexes by chain homotopy equivalences is a stable $\infty$-category. Taking the Verdier quotient by acyclic complexes thus provides a stable $\infty$-category as well, which is the unbounded derived $\infty$-category.

@D.-C.Cisinski If I understand correctly, given a small additive $\infty$-category $\mathcal A$, its non-abelian derived category $\mathcal P_\Sigma(\mathcal A)$ is pre-stable, thus it embeds into its stabilization. When $\mathcal A$ is an 1-category, I think that, the unbounded chain complexes modulo chain homotopy equivalences form a full subcategory of this stable $\infty$-category.

@D.-C.Cisinski Thank you! I was confused about how to conduct this Verdier quotient and compare it with the localization, but the theorem cited in David's edited answer explains that.

Thanks to Victor Saunier for pointing out a mistake in an earlier edit of this post.
Let $K(A) := N_{dg}(Ch(A))$, with $A$ a small category.
In the  Münster video series, around minute 20, it is shown by hand that $K(A)$ is a stable category, this is shown by explicitly writing down what a cofiber square is and seeing that it is both a pushout and a pullback.
The exact same proof applies to show that $K^{\mathrm{coh}=0}(A)$, the subcategory of all complexes with vanishing cohomology groups, is stable.
The set $W$ of quasi-isomorphisms is the set of morphisms with cofiber in $K^{\mathrm{coh}=0}(A)$, applying theorem I.3.3 from Nikolaus-Scholze shows that $\mathcal{D}(A)= K(A)[W^{-1}]$ is stable.

HA.1.1.4.4 is about limits rather than colimits

Sorry, I meant 1.1.4.6, I will correct my post.

1.1.4.6 only pertains to filtered colimits, which cofibers are not. Here, I think it's simply not true that the cofiber in $\mathrm{Cat}_{\infty}$ is stable; the localisation on the other hand is indeed stable, and this is proven in Theorem I.3.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01799

Thanks for the correction, I was too hasty in answering. I’ll correct my answer. Is there a way of describing what the cofiber in $Cat_\infty$ is?

If $A$ is small, it might be better to consider $D^b(A)$, the derived bounded category, which is also small. In this case, more is known: Corollary 7.4.12 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.02338 proves that for an exact category $E$ (in the Quillen sense, so this in particular applies to abelian categories), the map $E\to D^b(E)$ is the initial exact functor from E to a stable category.

I agree. But in the classical theory, people also considered unbounded derived category of small abelian categories. For instance, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.11261.

As David's answer below illustrates, the large derived bounded category is often constructed as a localisation, and this means one should probably be careful with the set-theory. For example, if your abelian category is locally presentable, then you should be able to reduce to the small case.

I am confused. What is the relation between the bounded derived category of a small abelian category with its stable envelope.

@Z.M unless I misunderstand what you ask, the above-cited theorem precisely says the two agree.

Oh, what I had in my mind was incorrect. I thought of stable envelope of additive categories, but here, we need stable envelope of exact categories.
